# uploading sql file via terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, terminal

I am trying to import big .sql file using Terminal on Mac. What should be displayed after I run this:

```
mysql -u username –ppassword database_name < /path/to/file/file.sql
```

and hit enter? My database is still empty, the terminal doesn't show any errors, but it displays info about Oracle and the long list of Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
etc.

I had an error before saying 'Access denied for user... ' and the problem was CREATE DATABASE with old db name, I have amended it to the new db name, now there is no error, just long list of help.

Have anyone got an idea what could be wrong, and what this help list means?

Comment: You should not have a space between the `-u` and username, change it to `-uusername`

Comment: Thanks, that helped me (everywhere I checked the space was suggested there!) - although removing the space before username didn't solve it completely, for some reason I couldn't use /path/to/file/file.sql but I had to go to the folder first using 'cd' and then just use: 
mysql -uusername –ppassword database_name < file.sql

Comment: My guess would be that you have a space in your path, so you will have to quote the path like: `mysql -uusername -ppassword database < "/path/to/file/with/space/file.sql"`

Comment: My guess is you want to be using a relative path instead of an absolute path. For example, the way you have it with the / first, that means that has to be the entire literal path of your script. But if you're already in /usr/foo/bar and you're trying to run a script in the directory "path" that is contained within "bar", there should be no slash first.

Answer (score 0):

I see you got your answer and fixed it. Here is an alternative to entering your username and password on the command line (often not considered a best practice, and tough to automate).

cd to /~
create .my.cnf

with the contents below

```
[mysql]
user=here_is_my_username
password=here_is_my_password
```

Then you can simply run commands like

```
mysql database_name < /path/to/file/file.sql
```